# Dividir el pago utilizado MercadoPago

Tags: mercadopago

Queria saber si existe la posibilidad de hacer un split/division de un pago utilizando MercadoPago. La division es para que se pague con dos tarjetas diferentes y vayan a parar a una cuenta. El ejemplo concreto que estoy buscando es el siguiente: Tengo un pago de 500 pesos, hay alguna forma de dividir el pago por ejemplo en 300 pesos con una tarjeta y 200 pesos con otra tarjeta y que vayan a la misma cuenta de destino?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Existe el concepto de pago con 2 medios de pago, puedes revisarlo en

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/related/multiple-payment-methods/

Debes activar el pago con 2 medios en opciones para mi negocio https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/settings/my-business

Y para solicitar el pago deberías usar una integración básica

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/receive-payments/

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias!!